# How to clone a 2d ArrayList of Objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have a 2d `ArrayList` named `objs` full of Objects and I want to ​copy `objs` into another ArrayList named `obj2s`. Also, I want no changes of `obj2s` to affect `obj` and vise-versa.

I know that I can't simply do `obj2s = objs` as that will just pass along the reference.

Casting `obj.clone()` to an `ArrayList` of Objects and setting `obj2s` equal to that won't work either as when I go to edit the objects inside `obj2s` it will edit the ones in `objs`.

So what can I do?

Comment: ArrayLists have a shallow copy constructor. You could iterate over the sub lists and create copies that way.

Comment: @Carcigenicate what about the objects inside the sublists?

Comment: Are they mutable? If they are, they'll need to have their own copy mechanism. If they're immutable, that's not a problem. Creating a copy constructor for the objects or implementing Cloneable would work, although I think Cloneable is generally regarded as broken.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that works! You can post an answer and I’ll mark it correct